# Send image with python Post to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

i have a docker instance running on an aws ec2 instance. on the docker container i have a flask server running. Now i am trying to upload a image file via post from a local python file. But somehow the file gets corrupted during upload. i am not able to open the image with Pillow.
on my local machine the file is correct

```
file testFolder/input.png
testFolder/input.png: PNG image data, 1024 x 1024, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

but on the server its broken

```
file input.png 
input.png: data
```

my client code:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as image_file:
    headers = {'x-api-key': apiKey}
    files = {'file': ('image.png', image_file, 'image/png')}
    
    response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

my server code:

```
if 'file' not in request.files:
    return 'No file part in the request'

file = request.files['file']

file_path = 'input.png'
with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(file.read())
```

if i copy the file via scp the file is correct.
for any tips i would be very grateful. thank you

Comment: what code is sending the image data? is it reading the bytes correctly and using multipart form to post?

Comment: It's in the post I think.  client and server

Comment: Does the application code work on a local system (not EC2) using your local Python (without Docker)?  This class of error doesn't seem like it'd be specific to either of these technologies.

Comment: yes the code is working on my local machine. @DavidMaze suppose it has something to do with the server. more interesting are the results if i calculate the file size:
`
Client:
File size before sending: 1140353 bytes
File size after opening: 1140353 bytes
{
 "file_path": "uploads/input.png",
}

Server:
2023-12-25 10:40:41 Received file size: 2078545 bytes
2023-12-25 10:40:41 Received file name: input.png
2023-12-25 10:40:41 Saved file size: 2078400 bytes
`

Comment: Can you add a more complete code snippet of how you're receiving the request on the server?